# Playing a video loaded via cdvfile:// in Cordova

Tags: angular, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-ios, cordova-plugin-file

### Updated Info

I've found that you can't use `cdvfile://` when using `cordova-ios 6.1.0` because of how `WKWebView` works. You now need to use `window.WkWebView.convertFilePath([your file path]);` to convert your path to something `WKWebView`.

I'm now using the `toURL()` method found when getting a `FileEntry` from the `cordova-plugin-file` plugin and feeding that value into `window.WkWebView.convertFilePath`.

I'm still getting a similar error, but I think I'm getting closer to cracking this egg:

```
Refused to load unsafe:app://localhost/_app_file_/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/{ID}/Library/NoCloud/videos/recording.MOV because it does not appear in the media-src directive of the Content Security Policy.
```

I added `app:` to the CSP and added `<access origin=app://* />` to `config.xml`.

Does anyone know how I can get rid of the error and get the video playing within the `<video>` element?

### Original Post

When trying to play a `cdvfile://` file in a `<video>` element I get the following error, even though I've added, what I think, is the correct properties to my Content Security Policy (found below):

```
Refused to load unsafe:cdvfile://localhost/library-nosync/videos/recording.MOV because it does not appear in the media-src directive of the Content Security Policy.
```

What is required to get a locally stored video file working in a basic `<video>` element using Angular + Cordova?

### Additional Information

I'm using `Angular 9.0.7`, `cordova 10.0.0` and `cordova-ios 6.1.0` to build an app that plays video recordings. Recordings are created using `cordova-plugin-media-capture 3.0.3` and saved to the local device using `cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2`.

I've added the following to my `config.xml`:

```
<access origin="cdvfile://*" />
<preference name="scheme" value="app" />
<preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
```

I'm also using the most open/insecure Content Security Policy I could find, with `cdvfile:` added to `default-src`, `connect-src` and `media-src`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
    default-src * data: blob: filesystem: about: ws: wss: gap: cdvfile: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
    script-src * filesystem: gap: cdvfile: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
    connect-src * filesystem: gap: cdvfile: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; 
    img-src * filesystem: gap: cdvfile: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; 
    frame-src * data: blob: ; 
    style-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline';
    font-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline';
    media-src * filesystem: gap: cdvfile: data: blob: mediastream: ;
">
```

In the documentation for the `cordova-plugin-file` plugin ([link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html#cdvfile-protocol)) they provide an example Content Security Policy, but it doesn't appear to be valid:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
    default-src 'self' data: gap:cdvfile:https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
    media-src *
">
```

When using the above, I get the following error on load:

```
The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'default-src' contains an invalid source: 'gap:cdvfile:https://ssl.gstatic.com'. It will be ignored.
```

The only way to remove the error is to add a space betweem `gap:`, `cdvfile:` and `https://ssl.gstatic.com`. I ended up removing `https://ssl.gstatic.com` to make the CSP as generic and "open" as possible.

### Even More Information

I can load the MOV file and validate that is exists using the following:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL([PATH TO FILE ENTRY], entry => {

    entry.getMetadata(metadata => {
        console.log(metadata); // If metadata.size exists and isn't 0, I believe I have the file
    }, err => {
        console.error(err);
    });

});
```

Once I have the file (variable named `entry` in this example) I use the following in my component to get the filepath:

```
let videoSrc: string = entry.toInternalURL();
```

This get's me the `cdvfile://` path that I then use as the source to play in my video element:

```
<video *ngIf="videoSrc" id="video" width="640" height="360" preload controls>
    <source [src]="videoSrc" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

... So, yeah. That's my life story... Can anyone shed some light as to what's required to allow me to play local `cdvfile` files in a standard `<video>` element?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add an **explicit permission** for `app:` in the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"`.

```
        <!-- Enable all requests, inline styles, and eval() -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
        default-src * app: gap: data: cdvfile: android-webview-video-poster: file:; 
        style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; 
        script-src * 'unsafe-inline'">
```

(For some reason `default-src *` wasn't enough.  I had to add `default-src * app:` to make it work on `http://` urls.)
It also appears to work if you just don't have a `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"` at all.

---

*My life story since it took me a long time to figure out why it wouldn't be working for you:*
**I can confirm that this should work.**
**Based on your "Updated Info"...**

I am doing exactly what you are with cdvfile > nativeUrl > schemeUrl

- The schemeUrl works for me.

When I use the schemeUrl in an `<img>` and `<video>` src tag on:

- a page with a schemeUrl (`app://localhost/...`):

  - No problems.
- a page with an `https://...` url:

  - A warning: "The page at *https://...* was allowed to display insecure content from *app://localhost/...*"
  - but it works.
- a page with `http://`

  - I get the warning you received.

**Notes / Other possibilities thoughts:**
Your `<access origin=app://* />`
Should probably be `<access origin="app://*" />`
But I don't think this is your problem as I don't have an `<access origin/>` tag at all in my config.xml.

You can try adding:
`<allow-navigation hap-rule="yes" href="app://localhost/*" />`
to your `config.xml` (same place where you would have `<access origin=.../>`)
But I also just tried my app without this and it was fine.

You could also try upgrading to cordova-ios@6.1.1